# Delphi LiveBindings TPrototypeBindSource and customFormat

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, livebindings, custom-formatting

I use business classes with a TPrototypeBindSource. I will use CustomFormat to concatenate 2 fields. I am coming with a TBindSourceDB but not with the TPrototypBindSource.

I use an TEdit and a TLinkControlToField.

If I use : %s + " text" => it's work fine.
When I use it with a TBindSourceDB, that works fine

```
%s + " - " + Self.Owner.FieldByName('Enseigne').text
```

But I don't understand how to access of data when I work with TPrototypeBindSource.

[image]

[image]

Could you give me the syntax for concatenate 2 fields with business classes bind ?

Comment: Why don't you just have an extra field in your business object that returns the concatenation of the fields you are trying to add together on the control side?

Comment: Because the responsabilty of business object is just store the datas (MVVM). The concatenation is a constraint of my view. And I would like just use the customFormat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd have another go at an answer as you didn't seem to have much enthusiasm for my first one.

Before addressing your q, let's try a little experiment.  In a project that has a DataSet
with persistent fields FieldA and FieldB, say, set up a BindSourceDB and BindingList and add
two TLinkControlToFields to link these fields to two TEdits, edFieldA and edFieldB.

Test that it works as expected, then add another TEdit, edOther, and another TLinkControlToField, LinkControlToField3.   Set its control to edOther, DataSource to the BindSourceDB and its FieldName to FieldA.  Set its CustomFormat to

```
Name
```

Compile and run, and you should find that edOther displays the name of FieldA's Field component, DataSetFieldA or similar.  What's going on, obviously, is that LiveBinding's
expression evaluator is using the TField component of FieldA as the "scope" it uses to
identify which `Name` property is being referred to.

Now, replace `Name` by `Owner.Name`

and at run-time edOther should display `Form1` or similar, because persistent fields are owned by their containing form or datamodule.  So, referring to Owner.Name broadens the scope within which identifiers in the `Format` expression can be resolved and their values extracted.

So, using a BindSourceDB as the link's datasource, you can set the `CustomFormat` to something quite complex, e.g.

```
LowerCase(Owner.DataSet.IndexFieldNames) + ' ' + Owner.DataSet.FieldByName('ID').Text
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with the default set-up of a `PrototypeBindSource`.

Continuing our experiment, set up a project using a PrototypeBindSource with two fields
FieldA and FieldB and three TEdits, as before. Notice that this time, if you try to set the `CustomFormat` of LinkControlToField3 to `Name` you will get an error message 'Could not find Name', I think because the LB machinery is unable to resolve the reference to Name because of the abstracted implementation of fields in TPropotypeBindSource.

However, all is not lost.  Remove LinkControlToField3 and instead, add to the Form's BindingList a BindExpression.

Set the BindExpression's ControlComponent to `edOther`, its ControlExpression to `Text` and its SourceComponent to `Form1`.

With that done, in the SourceExpression, we can refer to properties of Form1 and its components, with an expression like this one

```
edFieldA.Text + ':' + edFieldB.Text
```

which works fine for me.

One thing that I haven't managed to find out yet is which the SourceExpression can't include things like `LowerCase`.  However that's easily worked around, by adding a `MyLowerCase` function to Form1 and LB is quite happy with that.

So, I think that answers your q of how to concatenate the contents to two controls (or fields).  Personally, I would still prefer to use a concatenated property of the business object, but ymmv.

Comment: Yes, I hunderstand, and your exemple works fine. I have just need to call "BindExpression1.Evaluate;" in my case. For you and for create a new application, the livebinding with OO model (MVVM) it is a good way ?